# What's the best way to deal with nullable state variables with React and TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following component which fetches an array of articles, displays a loading spinner, and finally displays the list of articles. It has a typing error.

```js
const ArticleListContainer: React.FC = () => {
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState<Article[] | null>(null)
  const [isFetched, setIsFetched] = useState<boolean>(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchArticles()
      .then(data => setArticles(data))
      .then(() => setIsFetched(true))
  }, [])
  return isFetched ? <LoadingSpinner /> : <ArticleList {articles} /> // Error!
}
```

The problem here is that `articles` is *nullable*. The `articles` prop accepted by `ArticleList` cannot be null.

However, I know that if the data has been fetched, `articles` cannot be null. This relationship becomes more clear if I use a custom hook to fetch articles.

```js
const ArticleListContainer: React.FC = () => {
  const { data: articles, error, isFetching } = useAsync(fetchArticles)
  if (isFetching) {
    return <LoadingSpinner />
  } else if (error !== null) {
    return <ErrorPage />
  }
  return <ArticleList articles={articles} /> // Error!
}
```

By design of `useAsync`, if `isFetching` is `false` and `error` is `null`, `articles` cannot be `null`.

Here are some workarounds I came up with.

**1. Check for null**

```js
if (articles === null) {
  throw new Error('Articles is null!')
}
```

I shouldn't have to do this since this code will (theoretically) never be used unless the return value of `fetchArticles` is null.

**2. `!` operator**

```js
return <ArticleList articles={articles!} />
```

It's probably not a good idea to put a bunch of `!` operators everywhere.

Is there a better way to write/type this component?

Comment: Not in this example. If I had multiple pieces of state that needed to be fetched (i.e. `A`, `B`, and `C`), I think it would be nicer to have some variable that indicates if any data is still being fetched, instead of doing `if (A === null || B === null ...`. Also, I simplified this example from redux, which seems to encourage using an `isFetched` state.

Comment: I think whoever posted their comment deleted it? It was a valid point; they suggested I remove `isFetched` since I can just use `articles === null` to check if data has been fetched.

Comment: How about passing an empty array as a fallback: `<ArticleList articles={articles || []} />`

Comment: Hmm... that does seem like a relatively clean solution. I will try that, thanks.

Comment: You already tracking the state of the fetch and render based on that, you can set the initial state of the articles to an empty array

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to model the state with separate `useState` hooks, but `articles` and `fetched` state variables are strongly interrelated - no fetched article without having loaded it before.

It is probably a good idea here to handle all possible states and their transitions in a single state complex/hook similar to a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). TypeScript can help us with [discriminated union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) to make decisions about the recent state ([StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-fz2f1j)):

```
// State types
type State = Loading | Fetched | Error
type Loading = { type: "loading" }
type Fetched = { type: "fetched"; articles: Article[] }
type Error = {type: "error", message?: string}

const App = () => {
  // initially set state to fetched with no articles
  const [state, setState] = useState<State>({type: "fetched", articles: []})
  useEffect(() => {
    setState({type: "loading"}) // change to loading
    fetchArticles().then(setState) // change to fetched, when done
  }, [])
  return state.type === "loading" ? 
  <div>loading... </div>:  
  state.type === "error" ? 
  <div>upps... </div>: 
  <div>{`fetched: ${getArticleNames(state.articles)}`}</div>
}

// just some helper methods/types
type Article = {name: string}
const getArticleNames = (articles: readonly Article[]) => articles.map(a => a.name)
const defer = (ms: number) => new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(()=> resolve(), ms))
const fetchArticles = () => defer(2000).then<Fetched>(
  ()=> ({type: "fetched", articles: [{name: "fooArticle"}]}))
```

If you need a bigger example, [here](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#designing-the-state-shape) is a nice one with Redux.